# Double integrals combined range question

Tags: probability, integration

A joint distribution has the following probability function:

$ P(X = x,Y = y) = \frac{1}{11}|x−y|$ for $x = 0,1,2;$  $ y = 1,2,3 $

Find $P(X + Y ≥ 3)$

I am unsure what this is asking me to find. I have initially calculated the double integral assuming it meant $ P(X ≤ 2,Y ≤ 3) $ which provided an incorrect answer obviously. My reasoning being that is what the variables are defined for.

How do I approach calculating this correctly? Do I calculate separate integrals for every possible combination of X and Y that could add up to 3 or more? That seems quite exhaustive.

Comment: "*Do I calculate separate **integrals** for each combination*"  It seems pretty silly to call a discrete calculation an "integration" to me... There are nine possible outcomes in the sample space $(0,1),(0,2),(0,3),(1,1),(1,2),\dots,(2,3)$.  Of those $(0,3),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3)$ all satisfy $X+Y\geq 3$.  Add up the values of $P(X=x,Y=y)$ for each of those six points to obtain $P(X+Y\geq 3)$.  No calculus is required, and certainly no integration techniques.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the beginnings of the table for this joint distribution:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline x&y&x+y&P(X=x,Y=y)\\\hline 0&1&0+1=1&\frac{1}{11}|0-1|=\frac{1}{11}\\\hline 0&2&0+2=2&\frac{1}{11}|0-2|=\frac{2}{11}\\\hline
0&3&\color{red}{0+3=3}&\frac{1}{11}|0-3|=\frac{3}{11}\\\hline1&1&1+1=2&\frac{1}{11}|1-1|=0\\\hline 1&2&\color{red}{1+2=3}&\frac{1}{11}|1-2|=\frac{1}{11}\\\hline\vdots\\\vdots\\2&3&\color{red}{2+3=5}&\frac{1}{11}|2-3|=\frac{1}{11}\\\hline\end{array}$$

There are a total of $9$ possible outcomes corresponding to the possible pairs $(x,y)$ since the problem statement explicitly stated that $x$ is always one of the numbers $0,1,2$ and $y$ is always one of the numbers $1,2,3$

Note that the values in the far-right column should be adding up to one for this to be a valid probability distribution (they do, so we are fine).

This is a **discrete** distribution, there should be no "*integration*" in the usual sense happening.

To find the probability $P(X+Y\geq 3)$, simply look at the table for all of the scenarios where $x+y\geq 3$, and add their corresponding probabilities, so you will end up with a total of $\frac{3}{11}+\frac{1}{11}+\dots+\frac{1}{11}$ where the additional values in the middle of the summation correspond to those which I did not fill in on the table above.

(*If you wanted to save a little time, you could instead calculate as $P(X+Y\geq 3)=1-P(X+Y<3)$ instead and only need to look up three values from the table, but you would still need to recognize which values are necessary*)

Comment: Outstanding, thanks so much for taking the time to explain. You're a legend.